# Why i cant see in render view

Tags: rendering

Why i cant see in render view. I have a just a single window. In 3D i can view but when i press Shift+Z to render i cant see the window. I have Press W -> Clear all Restrict Render. I have check the Object cycle setting everything is tick mark.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The model is showing up for me. Perhaps you messed with what layers are rendering?

Comment: The same for me... I guess the above image was taken from a somewhat different file

Comment: I manage to get the same result as in the question, but after fiddling around I managed to see it. There are some serious issues with the object, could not ascertain if it was the materials or the mesh, but am leaning towards material as changing that had no effect but changing the mesh did...

Comment: @m.ardito and mark the file and the gif file are same not take from different file. As Below Nick mention that file has problem.

Comment: <kbd> tags around keyboard keys please.